# RealTime Update alert received from Facebook. What should I do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I do not know what I have to do any setting.

text-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Realtime Updates for Payments are an essential method by which you are informed of changes to orders made through Facebook Payments within your application.

If you haven't already updated the settings for Bowling King to support Realtime Updates, you have until May 13, 2014 to subscribe to and honor Realtime Updates for the payments object and begin calling the Graph API to update disputes.

If you do not subscribe and honor these Realtime Updates and begin calling the Graph API for disputes by May 13, Facebook reserves the right, under our Developer Payment Terms to withhold payouts and/or stop your app from accepting payments.

Please read about Realtime Updates and how to subscribe and callback as well as how to call the Graph API for disputes.

Make sure to enable the payments object setting and enter your callback URL and enable the migration setting for Realtime Updates
-------------------------------------------------------------------------text

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find everything you need to know under the following docs.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/payment/#realtime
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates